# Can I get the EntityManager from within an entity's class methods?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Is there an easy way to get Doctrine's entity manager from within an entity's class method?

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class MyEntity {
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

   [...]

   public function someFunction() {
     // Is there any way to get Doctrine's EntityManager in here?
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to do it. Your entities should not depend on EntityManager or Repository.

Comment: Forgot in my previous comment: Why do you need the EM in an entity?

Comment: Well, I was planning to create and persist another object in some cases, but I guess it is better to create it elsewhere. I did manage to get the EM by storing it in $GLOBALS, but I will try to refactor instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really not supposed to.  The idea behind a datamapper ORM like Doctrine is that your entities are just plain-old objects that know nothing about the persistence layer.  If you find yourself wanting an EntityManager inside your entity, that's a signal that you ought to be creating a service class of some sort.

That said, Doctrine is quite flexible.  For example, if you were so inclined, you could use [Doctrine as the foundation for an ActiveRecord-style ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/your-own-orm-doctrine2).

However, outside of very specific use-cases, I wouldn't recommend it.